# PYTHON: search for exact string in text document

Tags: python, database

I am trying to search a text file/database for an exact username but I am getting multiple outputs for my query

Here is my code:

```
import re
txtFile = open("test.txt", "r")
userName = raw_input("USER: ")
for line in txtFile:
    if re.match(userName, line):
        print line
```

When I enter a generic username like "dragon" I get multiple results:

```
>>>
USER: dragon
dragon:46.245.173.123

dragonsAreCool:3.13.136.5
```

How would I make the search exact instead of getting multiple results that include my query?

Comment: include the field separator: `dragon:`

Comment: as @TemporalWolf said, you should make your search more specific. additionally, it's good practice to use the syntax `with open("test.txt", "r") as txtFile:` and then indent everything that uses the file as it will automatically close the connection for you when completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
userName = raw_input("USER: ")
with open("test.txt", "r") as txtFile:
    for line in txtFile:
        if re.match(userName + ':', line):
            print line
            break  # if you sure there is only one user, add break, make you code faster, else delete it.
```

or:

```
for line in txtFile:
    if line.startswith(userName + ':')
        print line
        break   # if you sure there is only one user, add break, make you code faster, else delete it.
```